# product images are not being displayed in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, php

I'm using TatvaSoft's "7 in one" catalog extension for display new products on home page. its working fine on home page. But after clicking on "view all" link it redirecting me to 
`catalogextensions/index/newproduct/` page where all new products listed out. But On the same page there is no product image is showing up, instead of that magento placeholder empty image is appearing. I don't know whats going wrong in that.
there is only this much of code been written

```
<?php 
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
$code  = $store->getCode();
$enable = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalogextensions/config4/active',$code);
?>
 <?php if($enable == 1) { ?>
 <div class="maintitle">
        <div class="titlemain"><?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('catalogextensions/config4/title',$code); ?></div>
        <div class="viewall"><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('catalogextensions/index/newproduct'); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View All') ?></a></div>
     </div>
   <?php echo  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalogextensions/newproduct_home_list')->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
   <?php }  ?>
```

and one more thing I have noticed that each product images have same source i.e

```
media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/160x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/small_image.jpg
```

automatically it create a directory named as **cache** inside media/catalog/product.

Here is list.php

```
 class Tatva_Catalogextensions_Block_Newproduct_Home_List extends Tatva_Catalogextensions_Block_Newproduct_List
  {

 protected function _getProductCollection()
   {
    parent::__construct();
    $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToSort("entity_id","DESC")
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
        ->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInSiteIds())
        ->setOrder($this->get_order(), $this->get_order_dir());
    if(Mage::getStoreConfig('catalogextensions/config4/max_product'))
    {
        $products->setPageSize(Mage::getStoreConfig('catalogextensions/config4/max_product'));
    }


    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
    Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);

    $this->_productCollection = $products;

    return $this->_productCollection;
}

function get_prod_count()
{
    //unset any saved limits
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->unsLimitPage();
    return (isset($_REQUEST['limit'])) ? intval($_REQUEST['limit']) : 9;
}// get_prod_count

function get_cur_page()
{
    return (isset($_REQUEST['p'])) ? intval($_REQUEST['p']) : 1;
}// get_cur_page

function get_order()
{
    return (isset($_REQUEST['order'])) ? ($_REQUEST['order']) : 'position';
}// get_order

function get_order_dir()
{
    return (isset($_REQUEST['dir'])) ? ($_REQUEST['dir']) : 'desc';
}// get_direction

    public function getToolbarHtml()
    {

    }
    }
```

! please someone help me !

Comment: Can you post the code from `[Namespace]_Catalogextensions_Block_Newproduct_Home_List`? I think the problem is there

Comment: I've posted the same for u.. kindly look it !

Comment: The code looks ok (except for directly using `$_REQUEST` but this has nothing to do with the missing images - it just hurts my eyes to see code like that).  I see that the attribute `small_image` that is used in the product listing is added to the collection. Maybe you should ask the developer for support.

Comment: Contact the developer for support.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party module support.

Comment: Normally in the `list.phtml` is `thumbnail` used, I think, therefore you need to add the thumbnail attribute to the collection (if I'm correct)

Comment: Have you cleared your cache and reindex the catalog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is kind of off topic, but from a quick glance, try removing the line

```
->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
```

as it kind of kills the previous addAttributeToSelect('*')

Comment: hey thanks...nice trick, it works for me ..thanks a lot !!